How to get ros plugins for plotjuggler to work for jazzy jalisco?
Getting errors installing plotjuggler_ros with jazzy jalisco:
Starting >>> plotjuggler_ros
--- stderr: plotjuggler_ros
rosbag2_transport/qos.hpp: No such file or directory
10 | #include "rosbag2_transport/qos.hpp"
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/DataStreamROS2.dir/build.make:97: src/CMakeFiles/DataStreamROS2.dir/DataStreamROS2/datastream_ros2.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:223: src/CMakeFiles/DataStreamROS2.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
error: ‘using std::__shared_ptr_access<rosbag2_storage::SerializedBagMessage, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type = struct rosbag2_storage::SerializedBagMessage’ {aka ‘struct rosbag2_storage::SerializedBagMessage’} has no member named ‘time_stamp’
196 | const double msg_timestamp = 1e-9 * double(msg->time_stamp); // nanoseconds to seconds
| ^~~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/DataLoadROS2.dir/build.make:97: src/CMakeFiles/DataLoadROS2.dir/DataLoadROS2/dataload_ros2.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:195: src/CMakeFiles/DataLoadROS2.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Failed <<< plotjuggler_ros [14.3s, exited with code 2]
Summary: 24 packages finished [3min 2s]
1 package failed: plotjuggler_ros
12 packages had stderr output: examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_guard_conditions examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server examples_rclpy_minimal_client examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher examples_rclpy_minimal_service examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher launch_testing_examples plotjuggler plotjuggler_ros
